# What are all astrological information about sun?

Tags: scripture, astrology, navagraha

What are all astrological information about sun?
I want to know all residing deities like i have heard that indra,agni and shiva are. The opposite planets,opposite zodiacs its greatness and all **other facts** which are still unkown to me from puranas and other scriptures.

Answer (score 2):

**Description of Surya**

Consort: Saranyu & Chhaya

Original Color/Color: Red / Pink, Orange, Saffron

Guna: Sattva

Gender: Male

Element: Fire

God Associated (**Adhi Devta**): Agni

**Pratyadi Devata**: Shiva

Metal : Copper

Gemstone: Ruby

Body part: Bone

Taste: Pungent

Food: Wheat

Season: Summer

Cardinal Direction: East

Vansh: Surya

Day: Sunday

Friendly graha: Chandra, Mangala and Guru

Neutral graha: Buddha

Enemy graha: Shukra, Shani, Rahu&Ketu

Tone (Svara): Ga

Sun rules Number 1 in Indian Numerology.

You can learn more about Surya and other grahas from this [document](http://www.vedapatasala.com/divinetopics/009%20NAVAGRAHAS.pdf).

As per **Navagraha Suktam** each graha has three main levels:

1.Graha Devta (physical level)

2.Adhi Devta  (mental level)

3.Pratyadi Devta (soul level)

The Adhi devta defines the the nature of the graha. Since Agni is the Adhi devta,the nature of sun is fire and light.The pratyadi Devta defines the role and function of the planet.For sun,the Pratyadi Devta is Shiva,also known as Devon Ke Dev,i.e Lord of the Gods.Its shows that the sun is powerful,center of the navgrahas and a concept of self realization for people.Shiva being Pratyadi Devta of sun is the primary reason for sun to be **sattva** in nature.

Futhermore, as per [Matsya Purana](http://www.kamakoti.org/kamakoti/matsya/bookview.php?chapnum=12):

> Surya, Chandra, Mangala, Budha, Brihaspati, Shukra, Shani, Rahu and Keta are all expected to be basically benificient Grahas (Planets). Description of their Swarupas (Forms) is as follows:

For Surya:

> Padmaasanah Padmakarah Padmagarbha samuddhitah, 
>   Saptaashvah Saptarujjuscha Dwibhujah syaat sadaa Ravih

(Surya Deva has two hands wearing two lotuses, seated on a lotus flower; his luster is abundant like that of the outside part of a lotus; Surya Deva is comfortably seated on a magnificent chariot driven by Seven Horses).

> A Vedi (platform) is to be prepared with white rice grains with **Surya Deva the Center**, Mangal in the South, Brihaspati in the North, North East with Budha, East as Shukra, South East as Chandra, West as Shani, South West as Rahu, and North West as Ketu. **The Adhi Devatas to each of the Planets are as follows: Shiva for Surya, Parvati for Chandra, Skanda for Mangal, Vishnu for Budha, Brahma for Brihaspati, Indra for Shukra, Yama for Shanaischara, Kaala Devata forRahu and Chitragupta for Ketu. The Pratyabhidevatas respectively are Agni, Varuna, Prithvi, Vishnu, Indra, Aindri, Prajapati, Sarpa and Brahma.** Besides, Vinayaka, Durga, Vayu, Aakasha, and Ashvini Kumars and these are also to be invoked by individual names. While visualising the various Grahas, one has to visualise Mangala and Surya as of red colour, Chandra and Shukra as of white colour, Budha and Brihaspati as yellow, Shani and Rahu as black and Ketu as grey. The Kartha who is to perform the worship the Grahas should try to secure these coloured Vastras (clothing) and flowers as also apply Gandha (Sandalwood paste), offer Dhupa, Dipa and fruits.

Comment: @Effin forest **excellent answer** can you state do sun has a connection with indra or not i have read some where but cannot recall somewhere in wikipedia.

Comment: As per my knowledge Indra and Surya are brothers.They are known as Adityas-Sons of Adi.Indra is the eldest among them.

Comment: @Effin forest thanks i too think astrologically they don't have connection and sorry but i think you want to say  aditi

Comment: Yeah its aditi,sorry

Comment: no problem friend. :)

Comment: @Effin forest i have deleted those question marks in your quotes making it look bad i think its okay.